# Adding a default message to ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, reporting-services, rdlc

I have some reports with 2 tables and a chart in each. There are also several textboxes used for headings, a header and a footer.

I already know that if I want to set a custom message when no data is returned I can click on a report element (table, chart, etc) and in Properties, write it in the `NoRowsMessage` field.

However, because my reports contain several elements, the message is repeated several times. I think this looks ugly.

In addition, my textboxes, header and footer are all still shown.

Is there any way of hiding the whole report or preventing it from rendering, when there is no data, and simply showing a single message on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any specific functionality for this in SSRS, but you can try various workarounds to mimic this:

You can hide all elements in the report based on rows in a **Dataset** by adding a **Rectangle** the same size of the **Body** to the report, then adding all your report objects into the **Rectangle**.

Set the `Hidden` property of the **Rectangle** to:

`=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") = 0, true, false)`

This means that if there are no rows in the **Dataset**, the **Rectangle** and all its child elements will be hidden.

If you want one single message to be displayed, add a **TextBox** to the bottom of the report outside the **Rectangle** and set its `Hidden` property to the opposite expression:

`=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") = 0, false, true)`

So this way, you have one and only one message displayed when there are no rows in a **Dataset**. You also get the advantage of having more control over the No Rows message formatting.

You can do a similar thing for the **Header** and **Footer**. It makes sense to me to display these in all cases, but I guess it depends on your requirements.

So it's a pretty involved set of steps but might get you close to your desired result.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Haven't been able to try it yet - but it's the only valid answer.